format string and vararg - can I tell compiler to check them?
I have the following function for Logging purposes:
void LogE(const char* scope, const char* s, ...) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s : ", scope);
    va_list list;
    va_start(list, s);
    vfprintf(stderr, s, list);
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    va_end(list);
    fflush(stderr);
}

and it's called like this:
LogE(__func__, "No sufficient memory to add sorted triangle, current capacity (bytes) / requested (bytes): %d (%d) / %d (%d)", renderer->sortedTriangleCap, renderer->sortedTriangleCap * sizeof(SORTED_TRIANGLE));

If I would use printf function family directly, the compiler would complain/warn that the amount of varargs is less than the number of format specifiers in the format string.
Can I tell my compiler in C99 that const char* s and ... should be checked against each other?

What is your compiler? (Please [edit] your question to clarify.)

Could form a macro that does 2 prints.  Something like  #define LOGE(scope, s, ...) fputs(scope, stderr); fprintf(stderr, s,  __VA_ARGS__);.

This is doable via compiler extensions. For example, within GNU there is __attribute__((format(archetype, string-index, first-to-check))), defined here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html
In your case, you could add this to your function as...
void LogE(const char* scope, const char* s, ...)
  __attribute__((format(printf, 2, 3)));


is there no standard way of doing this?

@Raildex (Suggest to read the standard to find out yourself...) No.

@Raildex, no, there's no standard way.  Sorry.
